# Worklight project getting out of memory error when building

Tags: java, memory, ibm-mobilefirst, heap-memory

I started getting this error when trying to build and deploy all on one of my worklight project:

```
!ENTRY com.worklight.studio.plugin 4 0 2013-03-18 10:17:41.511
!MESSAGE FWLSE4002E: Failed to connect to HSQL database : Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (error in script file line: 84 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space)
```

I tried increasing my JRE VM memory by adding these arguments in my Eclipse preferences: `-Xms256M` `-Xmx512M`, but it didn't work. Is there something else I can try? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you make the heap even bigger like 1024MB?

Comment: Are you adding the memory to Eclipse or to the project running in Eclipse?

Comment: I tried making the heap bigger, still got the same error. I am adding the memory to eclipse, is there a project specific setting I can try? thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

You have to give the Worklight Server more heap size, not eclipse. The worklight server is basically a Websphere Application Server (WAS). Add the following line to the jvm.options file for your worklight server, located in workspace/WorklightServerConfig/servers/worklight/jvm.options:

```
-Xmx2g
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have 64bit Eclipse, try adding the following lines to your eclipse.ini file:

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m   
-Xmx1024m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops 
-Djava.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort=true
-Dcom.ibm.ws.management.event.max_polling_interval=1000
-Xms100m
```

Those are the recommended settings for launching WL Studio 64bit from the documentation.